# How do I add Reg2Mem pass to addRequired() in LLVM?

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I want to remove phi nodes from my llvm IR files, so I've read that Reg2Mem pass is a solution (why?).

I can easily use this pass from the `opt` tool by specifying `-reg2mem` as argument.

However, I want this functionality be built into my own pass called `FlattenO`. Therefore, I try to add the Reg2Mem pass as a required dependency of my pass (it should be called automatically then?).

```
void FlattenO::getAnalysisUsage(AnalysisUsage &AU) const {
    AU.addRequired<Reg2Mem>();
}
```

The code above doesn't work, because it cannot find any Reg2Mem pass. What files should I include to use the Reg2Mem pass? Also, please correct my code, so everything should work as intended.

Comment: What version of the LLVM API are you using?